# Writing a book that contains Apache-2.0 licensed code snippets

Tags: apache-2.0, books

If I want to write a book that contains code examples and snippets but also entire algorithms from an Apache-2.0 licensed source, what do I have to do to comply with the licensing terms? Apache 2.0 states that the license text must be distributed along the work independent of the media.

I cannot remember seeing a software development book that contained a full license text anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The license language says that you must provide the license with the code.

There are different ways how you can do this.

1. provide the license language on your website if the book is
   downloadable from that website.
2. provide the license language in an appendix to your book.

Please note that in case 1 you should include in your book a [statement like this](https://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#Apply-My-Software) as recommended by ASF.

Please also don't forget to provide proper attribution to the authors of the code you are using in your book (usually you can find that in the notice file).

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the full license text and meet other Apache license requirements.

If these are short pieces of code and only implementations of algorithms, check if they are not in the public domain, because they are not creative code but the implementation of simple algorithms. But it may depend on the jurisdiction.

Another option is to write to the creator and ask about custom license with only attribution.

But if you want to be 100% compliant with the Apache 2.0 License, you need to provide the full text of the license.

**This is not legal advice**